# List of names of ancestors of Prophet Muhammad(Peace be Upon him) upto ADAM(Peace be upon him)?

Tags: prophet-muhammad

Is there any tradition that mentions list of names of ancestors of Prophet Muhammad(Peace be Upon him) upto ADAM(Peace be upon him)?

Comment: There's no authentic source for this. Only a part of the lineage is agreed upon.

Answer (score 1):

You may find the lineage of the Prophet ﷺ mentioned in books of *Seerah* of which there are several. See for example [Ar-Raheeq Al-Makhtum](https://archive.org/details/TheSealedNectar_201501/page/n49). However its authenticity is not established.